# How to Bring a View Over a Flipper

Tags: famo.us

I'm trying to bring a view in front of a flipper

I use

```
StateModifier({
            transform : Transform.inFront
        });
```

on my view.  I then slide the view down "over" the flipper, however it seems to always go in behind the surfaces on the flipper.

Is there anyway other way of controlling the Z-Order?